# VBA: Referencing Macro on another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, templates, sharepoint

I have workbooks that loop code through all worksheets except certain sheets.
The code I have works fine but I am not trying to create a "macro template" on SharePoint that users can run the macro from.

Once I run the macro from excel 2016 (on sharepoint) it does not loop through other sheets.  Code below.  Any help is appreciated.

```vb
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Upload" Then
    ws.Activate
 
    Call Macro 
   'runs code through all worksheets except specified
     

  End If
           
Next ws
```

Comment: For clarification - the loop doesn't work when I reference the macro from another workbook (macro template that I'm trying to create).

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` references the workbook with the code. You either have to use `ActiveWorkbook` or pass the workbook as an object to the routine.